# Why can't I import my created modules when running a .py file outside of the IDE?

Tags: python, autohotkey

I'm trying to run a Autohotkey script that runs a .py file. The file runs normally until I import a module that I created (in this case "screeny_console"). Take this code for example:

```
import time
print("this works")
import screeny_console as sc
print("this doesn't work")
```

I'm not getting any erros. When I run it, a terminal window opens. In that window "this works" is printed, and after that the terminal window closes.

Can anyone here help me to solve this problem? Sadly I couldn't find the answer by googling it.

Comment: What errors are you getting and what is the contents of `screeny_console`?

Comment: I'm not getting any erros. When I run it, a terminal window opens. In that window "this works" is printed and after that the terminal window closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to @user56700. It was a problem in the contents of screeny_console. Inside that module was an line that imported a module from a folder that wasn't the one where the first module was located. I don't know why, but that made the program stop.